# Close android hybrid app that was builded by IntelXDK android build

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

I'm creating java script hybrid app with IntelXDK **android build** for android platform.
I'm unable to exit from my app using following code:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript"">

        function onLoad()
        {
              document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
        }

        function exitFromApp()
         {
            navigator.app.exitApp();
         }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad();">
   <button name="buttonClick" onclick="exitFromApp()">Click Me!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

The same code works well with IntelXDK **crosswalk build**.
How to close an app using **android build**?

Comment: Try to remove parentheses in the buttons onclick attribute.


 `<button name="buttonClick" onclick="exitFromApp">Click Me!</button>`


Then it will be executed when the button is clicked. Otherwise it is executed when the HTML is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

I checked and it does not work in the android build. There will be an update late March that updates the android build to a newer cordova. I verified that it works here. Maybe you can continue to use crosswalk build until then?

Comment: OK, thx. Will wait till April then. If android build will be updated to a 3.x cordova than why do we have cordova build option ???

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. Android cordova support works with some bugs like exitApp. We are fixing them but some people find the cordova support useful.